# Clicar em um campo com múltiplos resultados Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

No meu script de teste, estou fazendo uma busca no sistema que me trás 4 resultados.

[image: Resultado busca]

Preciso fazer um método que faça selecionar apenas um resultado específico(no meu caso o 4º).
Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não deu certo.

```java
//CÓDIGO DO MEU PAGE OBJECT "DSL"
public void selectResultBusca(By locator, String selecao){
        WebElement resultBusca = navegador.findElement(locator);
        Select combo = new Select(resultBusca);
        combo.selectByVisibleText(selecao);
    }

//CÓDIGO DE TESTE
dsl.selectResultBusca(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_"
                + "mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00\"]/tbody"), planoPrev);
```

Segue o HTML da página referente a caixa de busca da imagem.
Não coloquei todo HTML devido ter muitos caracteres.

```html
<div class="CM_lightbox" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <div class="CM_lightboxTitle">
                    <span>Procurar Registros</span><a class="CMLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl06','')"><span class="closeLightbox"><br></span></a>
                </div><div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_tsMain" class="RadTabStrip RadTabStrip_Default RadTabStripTop_Default RadTabStripTop">
                    <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
                        <ul class="rtsUL"><li class="rtsLI rtsFirst"><a class="rtsLink rtsBefore" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span class="rtsIn"><span class="rtsTxt">Busca</span></span></span></a></li><li class="rtsLI rtsLast"><a class="rtsLink rtsSelected" href="#"><span class="rtsOut"><span class="rtsIn"><span class="rtsTxt">Resultado</span></span></span></a></li></ul>
                    </div><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_tsMain_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_tsMain_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;selectedIndexes&quot;:[&quot;1&quot;],&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;scrollState&quot;:{}}">
                </div><div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_mpMain" class="RadMultiPage RadMultiPage_Default CMAutoSearchWrapper" style="max-height: 224.774px;">
                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_pvParams" class="rmpView rmpHidden CMAutoSearchComponentPnl">
                        <div class="CMAutoSearchComponentGroupPnl">
                            <span><div class="CMAutoSearchLinha">
                                <div class="CMAutoSearchLabel">
                                    <span>Plano Previdenciário</span>
                                </div><div class="CMAutoSearchMethod grid_3">
                                    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default" style="width:160px;white-space:normal;">
                                        <table summary="combobox" border="0" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                            <tbody><tr class="rcbReadOnly">
                                                <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl08$ctl04" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04_Input" value="Começa com" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"></td><td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table><div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;display:none;"><div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default "><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth"><ul class="rcbList"><li class="rcbItem">Começa com</li><li class="rcbItem">Contém texto</li><li class="rcbItem">Diferente</li><li class="rcbItem">Igual</li><li class="rcbItem">Não nulo</li><li class="rcbItem">Nulo ou vazio</li><li class="rcbItem">Nenhum</li><li class="rcbItem">Termina Com</li></ul></div></div></div><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                </div><div class="CMAutoSearchValue grid_4">
                                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl06_wrapper" class="RadInput RadInput_Default" style="white-space:normal;"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl06" name="ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl08$ctl06" size="20" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="TCS" type="text"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl06_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl08_ctl06_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;TCS&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;TCS&quot;,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;TCS&quot;}"></span>
                                </div><div>
                                    <input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl08$ctl08" value="" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl08$ctl08','')" class="CMAutoSearchCaseButtonOn" caseselection="On">
                                </div>
                            </div></span>
                        </div>
                    </div><div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_pvResult" class="rmpView">
                        <div class="CMAutoSearchComponentGroupPnl">
                            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default" tabindex="0">

                            <table class="rgMasterTable" border="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;">
                                <colgroup>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
<thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" class="rgHeader"><a onclick="Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.Sort($find('ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00'), 'Descricao'); return false;" title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl10$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl00','')">Plano Previdenciário</a></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead><tbody>
                                <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00__0">
                                    <td>TCSPREV/BRTPREV/Fund-Incorp</td>
                                </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00__1">
                                    <td>TCSPREV/BRTPREV/Alt-Incorp</td>
                                </tr><tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00__2">
                                    <td>TCSPREV/BRTPREV Incorp</td>
                                </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ctl00__3">
                                    <td>TCSPREV</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>

                            </table><div id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_SharedCalendarContainer" style="display:none;">

                            </div><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_ctl10_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">    </div>

                        </div><div class="CMAutoSearchButtonPnl">
                            <a class="CMLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl12','')"><span class="btnAdicionar">Confirmar</span></a><a class="CMLinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$placeHolderMain$mainWebCad$misPlanoPrevidenciario$mfsPlanoPrevidenciario$ctl00$ctl13','')"><span class="btnAdicionar">Selecionar todos</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div><input id="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_mpMain_ClientState" name="ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_misPlanoPrevidenciario_mfsPlanoPrevidenciario_ctl00_mpMain_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
                </div><div class="buttonContainer">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente, coloque o HTML da pagina na pergunta, assim podemos investigar o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Adicionei o HTML da caixa de busca. O HTML da página tem muitos caracteres.